# How to get column name for primary_key at database level?

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord

I need to get the column name containing the primary key(s) at the database level.

`Model.primary_key` returns `models_id` column name which is **not** the primary key at the database level. I cannot change migrations or modify the tables in anyway.

I can currently get it through the MySqlAdapter with `ActiveRecord::Base.connection.primary_key('table_name')`

but this does not work with tables that have composite primary keys. If the table contains a composite primary key it returns `nil`.

Is there any way I can achieve this programatically?

Comment: *"Is there any way I can achieve this?"* Check the INFORMATION_SCHEMA database and the [KEY_COLUMN_USAGE](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/key-column-usage-table.html) view pretty sure it's in there.

Comment: This needs to be done programatically. I'll update my question @RaymondNijland

Comment: Also, if you're suggesting to run a raw query rails side, I much rather not :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ActiveRecord does not support composite primary keys out of the box.

You'll need to install the [composite_primary_keys gem](https://github.com/composite-primary-keys/composite_primary_keys) and then `ActiveRecord::Base.connection.primary_key('table_name')` will return an array of column names if the primary key is composite.

Comment: thanks, this was an answer I didn't want but definitely works

Answer (score 0):

1. Execute the query:

   ```
   SHOW COLUMNS FROM table_name;
   ```

Then look at all the rows returned where the columns named **KEY** has the value **'PRI'**. Then column **Field** will give you the column name in your table that forms part of the table's primary key.

2. Alternatively:

   ```
   SELECT COLUMN_NAME FROM information_schema
   WHERE TABLE_SCHEMA='database_name'
         AND TABLE_NAME = 'table_name'
         AND COLUMN_KEY = 'PRI';
   ```